# Redirect everything that has /en/ to a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to have a multilingual website but I haven't finished english version yet so I would like to redirect if url has /en/ to a specific page with a content "Soon". This page would be www.sitename.com/en/welcome

I am doing this in Wordpress and I don't know .htaccess that good. This code actually works pretty good, it checks for language set and redirects accordingly, but the problem is that after visiting that url I want to go to www.sitename.com, it still redirects me to that page (probably since locale doesn't change).

```
   add_action("template_redirect", 'pl_redirect');
    function pl_redirect() {
      // if is english redirect to page id 193
      if (get_locale() == 'en_US' && !is_page(193)){    
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.sitename.com/en/welcome' );
        exit;               
      }
    }
```

How can I accomplish the same thing correctly?
I tried this in .htaccess but it doesn't work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 ^/en/$ /en/welcome
```

This is by Wordpress inside .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/en/$ /en/welcome [R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/en/?$ /en/welcome [R=301,NC,L]` - `Redirect` deals with strings not RegExps IIRC so that would be `Redirect 301 "/en" "/en/welcome"`

Comment: Thank you but I can't make it to work :/ I have edited code with what Wordpress puts in

Comment: I suspect the `RewriteBase /web/` is throwing a spanner in the works...

Comment: The site is temporary set on /web... so www.site.com/web/en should redirect to www.site.com/web/en/welcome

Comment: Actually - does the directory `/web/en/` actually exist? It's all about that router I think...

Comment: Hm it doesn't work. These kind of links are ok www.sitename.com/web/en/about-us but they should point to www.sitename.com/web/en/welcome Currently nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have actually installed everything in a directory called `/web` - you'll need 2 `.htaccess` files:

**/.htaccess** (the root WordPress .htaccess file)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# the base directory
RewriteBase /web/

# this means "don't rewrite /web/index.php"
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# this is a router any URL that's neither a file
# nor a directory will be routed to /web/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

**/web/.htaccess** (your rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/?$ /web/en/welcome [NC,L,R=302]
```